# If $G$ has no non trivial subgroups, then show that $G$ must be of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

If $G$ has no non trivial subgroups, then Show that $G$ must be of prime order. This question is from Herstein Page 46 Question 3.

Attempt:

Let $G$ has prime order(say $p$). By Lagrange theorem, order of the subgroup can be $1$ or $p$. So it has two trivial subgroups.

How do i prove the other way around?

Thanks.

Comment: "Let G has prime order(say p) .So by Lagrange theorem ,order of subgroup can be 1 or p .So it has two non trivial subgroups" These $are$ the trivial subgroups

Comment: @Jack  sorry i intended to write no non trivial

Comment: The result is not quite true, the group whose only element is $e$ has no non-trivial subgroups, and $1$ is not prime. Now suppose $G$ has an $a\ne e$. The subgroup $A$ generated by $a$ is cyclic, and because $G$ has no non-trivial subgroups, this group is all of $G$, so $G$ is cyclic. If $G$ is infinite cyclic, you can easily produce a non-trivial subgroup. Now take care of finite cyclics with composite order.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i understand what you have written ,How should i go about my proof

Comment: Only one item left to do. Let $n=ab$ where neither $a$ nor $b$ is equal to $1$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has a non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i am confused .you have proved if g is order p then G is cyclic

Comment: @AndréNicolas if G=e then the question is false

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out, the result does not hold for the one-element group. But any other group with no non-trivial subgroups has prime order. To prove that if the group has finite order $n\gt 1$ then $n$ must be prime, suppose $n=ab$ where neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1$. Then the group whose elements are $0,a, 2a, \dots, (b-1)a$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What is wrong with my attempt i have posted ?

Comment: It shows that a group of prime order has no non-trivial subgroups. You have **not** been asked to show this. You have been asked to show the converse.

Comment: @AndréNicolas if G is of composite order ,then say n=ab ,then by lagrange theorem it will have subgroup of order a and b .I f $Z_{
n}$ we have subgroups of orders which divides n .Does that violated composite order of G

Comment: I don't think you are quoting the Lagrange theorem correctly. But anyway, the first thing I showed is that if $G$ has no non-trivial subgroups then $G$ is cyclic, then we can easily argue that if $n=ab$ then the cyclic group with $n$ elements has a subgroup of order $b$, namely the one I identified earlier. It is time for you to absorb the answer given by Meelo, and the detailed outline I have given.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subgroups generated by one element - that is, those of them form $\{e,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$. Now, if $G$ is to have no non-trivial subgroups, then if we choose some $x$ other than the identity, this subgroup cannot be the trivial group - thus, for it to be a trivial subgroup, it's got to be the whole group $G$ (which, as an aside, means $G$ is a cyclic group). Now, to finish, consider: if $|G|=ab$, what can we say about the subgroup generated by $x^a$?

Comment: And it is not infinite.

Comment: @Dan True, though if you let $|G|=ab$ be cardinal arithmetic, with $a$ finite, it works fine in the infinite case.